# Change the headers content type with wp_remote_post

Tags: headers, wp-remote-post

Working with the remote API requests with WordPress. I have used `wp_remote_post()` function to request the HTTP data but I am unable to update the headers `Content-type` I am using the following code

```
 wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array("Content-type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"),
    'body' => array( 'username' => 'bob', 'password' => '1234xyz' ),
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);
```

But when I print the  response content-type is still `text/html` but the server require `urlencoded` content-type. 
How i can update the headers content type?

Comment: Default header is already `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What you see on printing response is response header which is control by server. The one you are setting is request header. So where is the issue ?

Answer (score 4):

So, you set the headers of a request using `wp_remote_post()` and you expect that headers be used in the response. That is what I understand from you:

```
When I print the response content-type is still "text/html"
```

I think that you are missunderstanding the HTTP headers. Using `wp_remote_post()` you make a request and you can set the headers of the request to whatever you need but obviously you can not control the headers of the response.

The headers of the response depends absolutely in the remote server.